# Get item by index in a tree control

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tree

I'm doing a drag and drop operation on a tree using some help from Adobe's quick Starts:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/working_with_tree/

The code suggested is roughly this:

```
var dropTarget:Tree = Tree(evt.currentTarget);
var i:int = dropTarget.calculateDropIndex(evt);
myTree.selectedIndex = i;
var node:XML = myTree.selectedItem as XML;
var drugXML:XML = XML(Tree(evt.dragInitiator).selectedItem);
if(node.localName() != drugXML.localName()){
    DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.NONE);
    return;
}else{
    DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.COPY);
}
```

This is all well and good, but I don't like the way it is selecting(highlighting) each item in the tree I'm dropping on, it's less clear where the item is going to drop. I want to implement this without the selection but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the XML of the node using just the index. I would like something like this:

```
var dropTarget:Tree = Tree(evt.currentTarget);
var i:int = dropTarget.calculateDropIndex(evt);

var node:XML = myTree.itemAt(i) as XML; 
//AFAIK itemAt(i) or anything like it does not exist

var drugXML:XML = XML(Tree(evt.dragInitiator).selectedItem);
if(node.localName() != drugXML.localName()){
    DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.NONE);
    return;
}else{
    DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.COPY);
}
```

So does anyone know what function is, or what I can do to extend the tree to have a function, like "itemAt(i)"

Thanks
~Mike

EDIT: I forgot to post that my current workaround is setting the selectedIndex = -1 after I get my node:XML. I'm afraid that if something bogs on the processor the user may see it select then deselect.

Comment: I think you're safe from visual feedback as long as you stay in the single thread (and don't trigger any validateNows)--the Flex framework won't get a chance to update the UIComponents.

Comment: I've seen others refer to threads, I have no idea what they are referring to, what is a thread in this sense and how would I spawn another one, or ensure I am only in one? I'm going to post another question for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simpler, though there may be gotchas:

```
var index:int = ...
var renderer:IListItemRenderer = tree.indexToItemRenderer(index);
var item:Object = renderer.data;
```

This won't work if the index is offscreen (since there might not be an active itemRenderer); shouldn't be an issue for drag and drop.

Comment: Thanks for trying so hard, there's no itemRendererToItem method for a tree, I can do itemRendererToIndex, but then we're right back where we started :-)

Comment: Sorry--the itemRenderer already owns the data, doesn't need an aToB function.

Comment: YAY! latest edit works! Thanks Michael, We should be able to trade rep in to buy people like you a beer.

Comment: Oh In case anyone needs to try this themselves, you will want to wrap Michael's Solution with "if(tree.indexToItemRenderer(index))", for some reason if you drag past the bottom of a list that index value goes way up so you get a null ref error when you try to assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

If your [`dataProvider`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Tree.html#dataProvider) is explicitly or implicitly a collection (see the linked docs for conversion rules), you should be able to use [`getItemAt`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#getItemAt%28%29) to resolve the index.

It appears that an `XML` provider will be converted implicitly:

```
var tree:Tree = ...;
var data:XML = ...;
tree.dataProvider = data; // could just as well be from MXML

var provider:ICollectionView = tree.collection; // tree converted it for us
trace(provider.getItemAt(index));
```

If you have something other than the convertible types (XML, Array, etc.), you might consider wrapping your `dataProvider` in an `XMLListCollection` or what have you to gain access to that method.

---

The above is aiming in the right direction but missing.

Turns out you don't want the `dataProvider` since `Tree` overrides that; you want the [`collection`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#collection) property (protected).  So you could override Tree and provide an `indexToItem` method to go with the `thisToThat` methods already present in `Tree`.

Comment: My dataProvider is an XML type. I had problems (probably my own lack of skill) making it work with the rest of my app when I made it an XMLListCollection.

Comment: Added some notes about how Flex will convert your XML to a collection.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it tells me getItemAt() is not a method of ICollectionView. So I just did "trace(tree.dataProvider.getItemAt(i))" since the doc says it was automatically converted to a list collection this should be no problem. When I run the code it crashes saying the index is out of bounds. Why would that be? And BTW I got some good answers back about the threads, so at least I know I'm good with what you said in the comment to the question.

Comment: I worked on it some more, threw in a break point to analyze the tree.dataprovider, it's an XMLListCollection but with only the 0 index which contains the XML of my tree. So it makes sense the getItemAt is failing.

Comment: Yeah, I think this avenue was a false lead.  I'm going to try again.  =)